# hdf5_create_file creates file with trailing '\000' characters

Tags: string, fortran, hdf5

I need to create a file with a name given at runtime. I have a vector of char of (len=80), with the name of the file followed by whitespace. I have tried

```
 call hdf5_create_file(handle, trim(filename))
```

where hdf5_create_file is a wrapper to hdf5 library.   Nonetheless, the resulting file has a sequence of trailing whitespaces. How do I remove those trailing whitespaces?

EDIT:

I am working on Linux. hdf5 v.1.10.3. filesystem is lustre. I have checked with `gdb` that, before passing `<filename>` to hdf5_create_file, `<filename>` internally looks like:

```
$5 = './filename.hdf5', ' ' <repeats 32 times>, '\000' <repeats 24 times>, ' ' <repeats 118 times>
```

Comment: What is your OS? What file system? What HDF5 version? What is the exact code you are executing? What is the exact resulting file name? There is not anything more than `trim()` that what you can do in Fortran. Does it really contain trailing blanks or some other kind of whitespace?

Comment: OK, we need more code. We need to know what *exactly* you are passing in the `filename` variable. Be aware that the 0 character is not a blank and `trim()` is not supposed to remove it. However, how does it get there in the first place? Perhaps some uninitialized variable?

Comment: The interface for hdf5_create_file might be useful as well - even better the code if it is not very long

Comment: Why are you using `hdf5_create_file` instead of `h5fcreate_f`?  The trailing `_f` means that `h5fcreate_f` is an HDF5 Fortran function.  If you use `hdf5_create_file`, you'll likely need to Fortran's ISO Bind C facility and NULL terminate the string.  Something like `n = len_trim(filename) + 1; filename(n:n) = C_NULL_CHAR`

Comment: The question refers to wrapper to HDF5 library.  That might be https://github.com/mpickem/hdf5_wrapper, which has hdf5_create_file

Comment: as @VladimirF pointed out, initialisation of filename was required. if you want to write your answer I will accept it

Comment: I do not think it can be answered from what the question shows, rather closed as "cannot be reproduced or caused by a typo".

Comment: well, it is an error due to lack of initialisation, worth to know for a new user. Anyway, as you prefer, feel free to close it

Comment: Lack of initialisation doesn't totally answer the question for me - if it is just a lack of initialisation of the variable filename it is an utterly remarkable coincidence that this uninitialised variable contains not only a valid filename, but also one with a sensible name in English. If it was purely due to lack of initialisation I would expect gibberish. It's not impossible what you see, but ...

Comment: @IanBush I wrote partially on a char vector that was not initialised, that is why there is a valid filename + clutter

Comment: At the very least you have to show, in the question, how you did the initialisation and how the variable filename is declared (char vector is not standard fortran  and could mean at least two things to me) for the question to be answerable.